# Random text app android

Tags: android

I was looking for a free open source code for a random text application, unfortunately I didn't found anything. 
I would like to start learning app develpment and I want to make an app with random text, when the button is pressed a text from my plain text show up above the button,something like that.
Has anybody a tutorial or a project with open source. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for that. Not complete but its what it represent. Place it in onCreate / button press or wherever. Just message me when you have problems.

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLetter);
final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";      
final int N = alphabet.length();
Random r = new Random();
String a = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N)));
tv.setText(a);
```

This is based on my randomizing app on playstore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.w2e.activities

Comment: I am begginer, I started to learn a month ago, I would like an example of app to make my own. I would like to make an app which show random text from my .txt file when i press the button. Anyway thanks for your answer I will follow.

Comment: Oh I see, I have random lists too.. Try exploring SQLite, my current code is unstable for the random text.